# What is the best word to collectively describe a street, suburb, town, district etc.?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

What is the best word to collectively describe a street, suburb, town, district, state, territory, country, continent etc.?

> In a sentence: He does not live in the same [street / suburb / town
>   etc.] as me.

The only two words I can think of are "region" and "locality". Which of the two is more appropriate? Are there any others?

Comment: *Place* should do?

Comment: Your question has been flagged for closure as "primarily opinion-based" because you ask for the "best" word, and there is almost never a single best word for any given situation. I would edit this out, as you are simply asking for a hypernym covering different scopes of location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both words are quite wide semantically.

According to Oxford Living Dictionary
(https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/) :

***REGION***

> : An area, especially part of a country or the world having definable characteristics but not always fixed boundaries.
>
> : An administrative district of a city or country.

***LOCALITY***

> : The position or site of something.
>
> : An area or neighbourhood.

But as ***REGION*** means only some area, not any place, in your case ***LOCALITY*** is more preferable because it can be used for streets as well.

Answer (score 1):

*Place* ([3a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/place)), as Kris suggests, and *area* ([4b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/area)) can be used as well and seem to be more common [according to the Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=live+in+the+same+place%2Clive+in+the+same+area%2Clive+in+the+same+region%2Clive+in+the+same+locality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20the%20same%20place%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20the%20same%20area%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20the%20same%20region%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clive%20in%20the%20same%20locality%3B%2Cc0).

[image]

Comment: Wow I’m definitely going to use Ngram viewer in the future. First time I’ve heard about it